# Why does £ appear as A£ in IE9 but not in FireFox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer, firefox

I have very recently discovered a problem with inserting a £ character into text, it displays as "£" in FireFox, but when I render the webpage in IE9 it appears as "A£" with an accent over the A?

The specific instance I am having issues with is:

```
<%= link_to "£150-£300", :controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action], :min_price => 150, :max_price => 300 %>
```

Both of these £ signs are prefixed with an "A" in IE9.  I have tried inserting the character in other `link_to` commands and I get the same behavior, so it isn't specific to this line.

I have also just checked and found that I get the same problem if I enter the symbol into plain text anywhere on the site.

Has anyone had similar problems in the past / know a remedy?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can avoid encoding problems by using [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp) for non-ASCII characters. For example, you can encode the pound sign as `&pound;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Â£` is UTF-8 encoded `£` misinterpreted in Windows-1252/ISO-8859-1. This means that the physical bytes the server sends are encoded in UTF-8, but the browser is not using UTF-8 to decode them. Following are tips to make browser interpret them in UTF-8.

You need the proper Content-Type header or at least declare it in html.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Note that if your server sends the proper HTTP Content-Type header with charset, that is considered over the html tag.

I don't know about Rails but this should set real HTTP header:

```
response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/html; charset=utf-8"
```

It could also be that you have explicitly set the character encoding in IE to Windows-1252 which would then make IE ignore the declarations coming from server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice - this and a combination of enabling the intranet settings through IE seemed to work...